# Convert from Columns to Rows

Tags: excel, matlab, converters

I wanted to convert a table data as: 24 hours (24 column), and 30 day (31 rows) become 1 column which with continue hours from 1-24 for the first day and for the second day so on.`

```
day/hours: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
1          A B C ........................................................
2          A'B'C'.....
...
31

Become
________________
day1/1hour   A
day1/2hour   B
day1/3hour   C
..........
day2/1hour   A'
day2/2hour    B'
....
day31/1hour  A'''
day31/2hour  B''' 
day31/24hour Z''''
```

Comment: You would use the reshape() function in MATLAB. I'm not sure about excel.

Comment: You would have to transpose before you reshaped in MATLAB - MATLAB uses column major order, and OPs data is in row-major order.

Comment: Thank you, If convert from col to Row is I can use reshape and transpose easily. But here it is till related to hours how to convert but 24hours continuing for each days until the end. Let say I have 24 x 31 and become 1 col x (24 hours x 31 days)rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is stored as a matrix `A`, then you can do this with a one-liner

```
A_asColumn = reshape(A',[],1);
```

Note the transpose `A'`, as MATLAB operates in column-major order, and that you can pass `[]` to `reshape` to mean 'the compatible number of rows'.

If your question is how to read a data table, then see the `textread` or `importdata` functions.

Comment: Thank you TheNoble So much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your table of values (including headings) is in D1:AB32.

Add the following:

- A1: "Day"
- A2: =QUOTIENT((ROW()-2),24)+1
- copy that down col A for 744 rows
- B1: "Hour"
- B2: =MOD(ROW()-2,24)+1
- Copy that down col B
- C1: "Value"
- C2: =HLOOKUP(B2,$E$1:$AB$32,A2+1,FALSE)
- copy that down col C